# apoc.meta.nodeTypeProperties mandatory output?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have recently been working with the apoc.meta procedure in neo4j.

I have this:

```
apoc.meta.nodeTypeProperties({labels:"Person", sample:2000)
```

The result gives back a column named "mandatory" for the different properties that appear in the nodes with label "Person". How is mandatory defined? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it indicates whether there is a node property constraint (only enterprise edition). See https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/

Comment: Yeah, this sounds very logical by reading the link. I hoped for something to check if the property exists in all the nodes with the given label but without putting a constaint in it.

Comment: For that, you do not need apoc. MATCH(n) WHERE NOT EXISTS(n.myProperty) RETURN count(*) > 0 AS notAllHaveIt     would get you taht